# Filter out elements from std::vector

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

I have ended up with the following code in order to filter out some bad elements from a `std::vector`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

typedef struct mystruct {
    int id;
    std::string name;
};

int main()
{        
    std::vector<mystruct> all_items = {{151, "test1"}, {154, "test4"}, {152, "test2"}, {151, "test1"}, {151, "test1"}, {153, "test3"}};
    std::vector<int> bad_ids = {151, 152};
    std::vector<mystruct> filter_items;

    for (const auto& item : all_items) {
        if ( std::find(bad_ids.begin(), bad_ids.end(), item.id) != bad_ids.end() ) {
            std::cout << "id: " << item.id << " is bad" << std::endl;
        } else {
            std::cout << "id: " << item.id << " is good item" << std::endl;
            filter_items.emplace_back(item);
        }
    }

    for (auto f : filter_items) {
        std::cout << "Good item: " << f.id << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Is there any more efficient way? Can the `std::remove_copy_if` or Boost be used here and how?

Answer (score 11):

You're essentially copying [`copy_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) with some additional debug messages. One can rewrite your code with

```
std::copy_if(all_items.begin(), all_items.end(), std::back_inserter(filter_items),
             [&bad_ids](const mystruct& item)
{
     return std::find(bad_ids.begin(), bad_ids.end(), item.id) == bad_ids.end();
});
```

But that's not necessarily more efficient, because `copy_if` and `remove_copy_if` are usually implemented as

```
for(; first != last; ++first) {
    if(predicate(*first)){     // copy if; remove_copy_if would negate
        *result = *first;
        result++;
    }
}
```

A more efficient way would be a faster predicate, e.g. instead of `find(bad_ids…)` you could use

```
for(const auto & item : all_items) {
    if(item.id < 151 || 152 < item.id) {
        filtered_items.push_back(item);
    }
}
```

But that's not as flexible anymore. That being said, we're talking about a small code snippet. As always, you should measure the time your code needs. And in this case, the output by `cout` will most likely take the most time.

For now, use the variant that you understand best. Your code is fine, there's not much one can improve at that point without resorting to personal preference because it's too short.

By the way, I would call `filter_items` `filtered_items` instead, since it doesn't actually filter items. It is a `std::vector` of items that have been filter**ed**.

Answer (score 5):

#### Pointless `typedef`

In C, it's fairly common to have a `typedef` like this:

```
typedef struct tag {
   // ...
} type_name;
```

This allows you define a variable with just `type_name var_name;`. A `struct` definition like this:

```
struct tag {
    // ...
};
```

...requires that to define a variable of this type, you need to type `struct tag var_name;`. In C++, that's unnecessary though. Using just:

```
struct type_name {
    // ...
};
```

... lets you define a variable as `type_name var_name;` already. In this case, you've left the final `type_name` off, so your `typedef` isn't syntactically correct. It's probably open to some question whether your code should compile at all (but either way, it's incorrect).

#### Container choice

A great deal here depends on the actual data. If the data you've shown is truly representative (there really are only a couple of bad IDs) your current choice of containers is probably quite good.

On the other hand, if this is a reduced sample, and in real use you might have dozens or even hundreds of IDs in your black list, then it's probably worth considering using something like an `std::unordered_set`.

#### Algorithm choice

Another obvious possibility (if the number of bad IDs might get large) would be to use a binary search instead of a linear search through the bad IDs. Note that you've shown in the bad IDs in sorted order--if you were to use a binary search, you'd be taking advantage of this, and their being sorted would be required, which it currently isn't.

#### Item grouping

Unless you're truly required to show the message about an item being good/bad in the order in which they originally appeared, I'd strongly prefer to see output something like this:

```
Good items:
A
B   
D

Bad items:
C
E
```

#### Avoid `std::endl`

I'd use `'\n'` instead of `std::endl`. Using `std::endl` not only prints a new-line to the stream, but also *flushes* the stream. This is rarely desirable or useful, and if you're producing a substantial amount of output, it'll typically cause a substantial slow-down.

#### Don't repeat yourself

I'd rather have a single function that does the formatting and display of the output, something on this order:

```
template <class It>
void show(std::string const &caption, It beg, It end) { 
    std::cout << caption << ":\n";
    for (; beg != end; ++beg)
        std::cout << beg->id << "\n";
}
```

#### Format data

Instead of putting all the contents of your `vector` on one long line, consider formatting it with (for example) one item per line:

```
std::vector<mystruct> all_items = {
    {151, "test1"}, 
    {154, "test4"}, 
    {152, "test2"}, 
    {151, "test1"}, 
    {151, "test1"}, 
    {153, "test3"}
};
```

#### Library usage

What you're really doing is starting with a collection of items, and partitioning it into two groups. That being the case, I'd at least consider using `std::partition` to do the partitioning part:

```
int main() { 
    std::unordered_set<int> bad_ids { 151, 152 };
    std::vector<mystruct> all_items = {
        {151, "test1"}, 
        {154, "test4"}, 
        {152, "test2"}, 
        {151, "test1"}, 
        {151, "test1"}, 
        {153, "test3"}
    };


    auto part = std::partition(all_items.begin(), all_items.end(),
        [&](mystruct const &s) { return bad_ids.find(s.id) != bad_ids.end();});

    show("bad items", all_items.begin(), part);
    show("Good items", part, all_items.end());
}
```

Comment: I would like to vote up for the std::partition approach. The original problem does not state that it is mandatory to remove items considered as "bad". I would assume "filter" means literally separate valid items from invalid. For this purpose seems the std::partition is the proper use case: split container in two parts, provides easy\efficient approach to traverse through valid items via 2 iterators, as result provides easy\efficient approach to remove redundant items when it really would be required.

Answer (score 3):

Yes there are better ways:

But exactly what will depend on your want. Do you want to maintain the original vector?

Zeta has shown several techniques that maintain the original container (by using copy). Personally I think that is wrong as copy is inherently an expensive operation.

If you want filter out I would say you want to remove bad items (effectively destroying the original). The the standard `Erase Remove Idiom` is the technique to use.

```
ids.erase(std::remove_if(std::begin(ids), std::end(ids), isBadId), std::end(ids));
```

The `std::remove*()` algorithm "moves" all the bad elements to the end of the container (returning an iterator to the first bad elemenet). Then the erase will "erase" from the container from that point to the end.

Another alternative is to split the container into two. One of bad values and one of good values. A bit more work. But can be made relatively efficient by using `std::move(<stcBegin>, <srcEnd>, <dstBegin>)`

```
 // Find all the bad elements and "move" them to the end, by using swap,
 // of your container. Note this is a usually a move (not a copy so cheap).
 auto firstBadValue = std::end(ids);
 for(auto loop = std::begin(ids); loop != firstBadValue; ++loop) {
     if (isBadId(*loop) {
         std::swap_iter(loop, --firstBadValue);
     }
 }

 // Now "move" one set of the elements from the original container
 // to the new container. Remember to reserve enough space to prevent
 // resizing.
 std::size_t            badSize = std::distance(firstBadValue, std::end(ids));
 std::vector<mystruct>  badValues;
 badValues.reserve(badSize);
 std::move(std::make_reverse_iterator(std::end(ids)), std::make_reverse_iterator(firstBadValue), std::back_insert_iterator(badValues));

 // Now that you have moved the elements out.
 // Reset the correct size of your original container.
 ids.resize(ids.size() - badSize);
```

The other thing I would note about your code is the use of `container.begin()`. The standard now provides `std::begin()` and `std::end()`. By using these functions you make your code easier to re-use with different container types (especially if you want to use C-Arrays).

Note: In the code above I use `badIds` as a filtering function. Filters are easy to write as lambdas.

```
 auto isBadId = [&bad_ids](mystruct const& item) {
     return std::find(std::begin(bad_ids), std::end(bad_ids), item.id) != std::end(bad_ids);
 }
```

But writing your filter like this (or as a separate function) is always a good idea. It makes your code more readable. This is called self documenting code. If we look at your original code and replace the test with a functor it make it more readable:

```
// Original Code.
for (const auto& item : all_items) {
    if ( std::find(bad_ids.begin(), bad_ids.end(), item.id) != bad_ids.end() ) {
        std::cout << "id: " << item.id << " is bad" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "id: " << item.id << " is good item" << std::endl;
        filter_items.emplace_back(item);
    }
}

// Self documenting code:
// Easier to read and deduce things about.
for (auto const& item : all_items) {
    if (isBadId(item)) {
        logItem(asBad,  item);
    } else {
        logItem(asGood, item);
        filter_items.emplace_back(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: `std::remove_if` is not partitioning algorithm. From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove): `[...] but the elements themselves have unspecified values (as per MoveAssignable post-condition). [..]`. Thus, splitting approach is incorrect. Still upvoted though. I hope you don't have the splitting approach in your code base :) Also, I've experienced issues with it, so it is not just text. I believe Snowhawk with another user told me about this, so I learned the hard way.

Comment: @Incomputable: That should fix it.

Comment: Yes, but I believe `last` should be `firstBadValue` and moved to the top, or assigned to.

Comment: @Incomputable: Fixed and reversed the iterators to make the result stable.

Comment: Great. I didn't notice instability, I guess now it can be refined into some more general purpose algorithm. It will be great exercise for OP in iterator based algorithms.

Comment: Rather than using your own loop you can use std::partition with a predicate, that should order the array correctly

Comment: @HaraldScheirich, Loki wants algorithm to be stable. And from cppreference page: `Relative order of the elements is not preserved.`.

Comment: Well,  then use std::stable_partition

Comment: *"Personally I think that is wrong as copy is inherently an expensive operation."* We only have a toy example at hand. If the original collection is necessary, `copy_if` (or `remove_copy_if`) is perfectly fine. If the original collection can be thrown away, the remove-erase-idiom is the way to go. Note that the latter copies too many elements if you still need to retain the original container. "Expensiveness" in this case is a matter of context (and the context here is damn small to work with).

Comment: Actually std::remove_if moves all the elements which are "good"